# How to update value in array in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-update

For example, Documents.

```
[
  {
    "username": "joy",
    "size_info": [
      {
        "data1": "apple bear cat",
        "data2": 100
      },
      {
        "data1": "dog eat fog good ",
        "data2": 100
      },
      {
        "data1": "hug ill jump",
        "data2": 100
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to update the document like below.

`data3` is the value split by space after getting 2 words from `data1`.

When I use `$substr`, I get an error:

> can't convert from BSON type array to String

```
[
  {
    "username": "joy",
    "size_info": [
      {
        "data1": "apple bear cat",
        "data2": 100,
        "data3": "apple bear"
      },
      {
        "data1": "dog eat fog good ",
        "data2": 100,
        "data3": "dog eat"
      },
      {
        "data1": "hug ill jump",
        "data2": 100,
        "data3": "hug ill"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is it possible? Thank you for helping.

Comment: Will be great if you can attach your current implementation, so we can know where you stucked at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pre-requisites: Have to update the records with the aggregation pipeline.

**Solution 1: With regex**

1. `$set` - Set `size_info` array.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate the element in the `size_info` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterated document with the result from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. A document with `data3` field. Get the first capture element from the result with the regex that captures the first two words.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      size_info: {
        $map: {
          input: "$size_info",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                data3: {
                  $first: {
                    $getField: {
                      field: "captures",
                      input: {
                        $regexFind: {
                          input: "$$this.data1",
                          regex: "^([^\\s]* [^\\s]*).*$"
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Pe-RA8hiswi)

---

**Solution 2: Get the first N element with [`$firstN`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/firstN/)**

Pre-requisites: MongoDB version 5.2

1. `$set` - Set `size_info` array.

   1.1. `$map` - Iterate the element in the `size_info` array and return a new array.

   1.1.1. `$mergeObjects` - Merge the current iterated document with the result from *1.1.1.1*.

   1.1.1.1. A document with `data3` field. Trim the result returned from `$reduce` operator which will:

   a. Split the `data1` by space into an array. And take the first 2 elements.

   b. Concat the value from the array (result from *a*) into a string with space.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      size_info: {
        $map: {
          input: "$size_info",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$this",
              {
                data3: {
                  $trim: {
                    input: {
                      $reduce: {
                        input: {
                          $firstN: {
                            input: {
                              $split: [
                                "$$this.data1",
                                " "
                              ]
                            },
                            n: 2
                          }
                        },
                        initialValue: "",
                        in: {
                          $concat: [
                            "$$value",
                            " ",
                            "$$this"
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QGffz8YwArT)